# IBM Bluemix: How to extend the memory allocated for Container group apps in bluemix space?

Tags: ibm-cloud

We have corporate account with bluemix. For any space we create, we get limit of 2 GB memory space for application deployment. Is there any configuration where we can extend this? or does it require any changes in account settings? Please suggest.

Comment: Raise a ticket on Bluemix. They will get back at you

Answer (score 0):

An user with the role of “Manager” of the organization account can modify the memory quota limits for the spaces under that origination.